# Qual objetivo do operador <=> no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, operadores, null

Fazendo ainda uma série de testes no MySQL reparei que o operador `<=>` funcionou equivalente ao `=` para o caso testado, esse abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE avatar <=> NULL
```

Isso retornou os únicos dois itens que possui na base, tanto para `<=>` quanto para `=`. Outro teste que fiz foi com o `<>`, no qual retorna todos os itens que que a coluna `avatar` é diferente `NULL`, para este `select` a cima.

Qual objetivo do operador `<=>` no MySQL? De fato existe equivalência com o operador de igualdade? Quando deve ser usado?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É o "igual" que trata do nulos sem causar problemas. Então o nulo é tratado como um valor **normal** mas diferente de todos os outros. O comportamento normal é que uma operação que envolver um valor `NULL` sempre resulte em `NULL` Ele muda isto.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/EqualNullOperator.sql).

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

No seu exemplo dará verdadeiro ou falso de acordo com o valor de `avatar` que espera-se não ser nulo. Se usasse o operador de igualdade simples resultaria sempre em `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

O operador que você usou é o "Null safe equal". No "=", se um dos dois lados for NULL, ele vai retornar NULL, neste aqui, retorna 1 se ambos forem NULL e 0 se um deles for NULL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html